# Get region EC2 is deployed to using Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to get the region an EC2 is running in using Node?

```
var region = ???

if(region == 'us-west-1')
    console.log("I'm in us-west-1");
```

Comment: Use the metadata service: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you're going to get is picking up the availability zone from the ec2 instance metadata:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

Full guide here:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html
```

You can get the region from the zone by removing the last char from the az. you can also future proof it by doing it as described here:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html
```

Comment: For a moment I was struggling with this because I thought the "169.254.169.254" was the local ip,  now I understand it's a special ip address.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah. it's a special ip that's going to be there on any ec2 instance